# Webpack ignores scss files, even when importing

Tags: webpack, sass

I am following these [sass-loader instructions](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) to the letter, but webpack won't bundle my `.scss` files into a `css` file.

I guess I need to import the `.scss` file - this isn't mentioned in the docs! - so I added this to `index.js`:

```
import styles from '../scss/style.scss'
```

Sadly this has no effect. Also, I don't really see why you would want to import css into javascript? You just end up with an unused variable...

Webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader"
        }]
      }]
  }
};
```

Why is webpack ignoring my scss files?

Comment: What about `require('../scss/style.scss');`?

Comment: Hm, no, `import` works as well. I think I found the issue... the above config does not create a .css file but the style magically DOES appear in the dist project. I suppose javascript injects the styles somehow... this is all very opaque to me... :)

Comment: Well, unless you are using styled components there's no need to define your import with a var. Using just straight up import '../../file/location.scss' is sufficient. Then in your production webpack config you can setup an ExtractTextPlugin using the css-loader and sass-loader to extract your scss to a css directory in an asset folder.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot to wrap your head around! Why wouldn't you use the ExtractTextPlugin in the dev environment?

Comment: @Kokodoko There's really no reason to expend the resources to extract the scss into it's own file in dev mode. If you have hot reloading enabled in your dev env it would have to write the file every single time. It's usually faster to let javascript load it. But when serving up the site on a server in production having the css file is often times more advantageous than loading all styles through javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack will ignore the unused varible by default for performance. Instead, try `import '../scss/styles.scss'` to load your scss file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what the loaders you're using actually do:

- `scss-loader` compiles SCSS to CSS.
- `css-loader` outputs CSS as a string.
- Most importantly - `style-loader` *injects the CSS into the head of the page at runtime*. It doesn't create any files in the final output!

If you want to have the CSS be in a separate file (which is a good idea in production, to avoid a flash of unstyled content), you need to use [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin).